# Proving $\omega_1$ is inaccessible in $L(r)$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

I am trying to prove that $\omega_1$ is strongly inaccessible in $L(r)$ for all $r \subseteq \omega$ from the assumption that $\omega_1$ is inaccessible to reals, i.e., that $\omega_1^{L(r)} < \omega_1^V$ for all $r \subseteq \omega$.

I have managed to prove that $\omega_1^V$ is an uncountable regular cardinal in $L(r)$, but failed at proving it is also a strong limit.

The class $L(r)$ is defined by transfinite recursion as follows:

- $L_0(r) = \mathsf{trcl}(\{r\})$;
- $L_{\alpha+1}(r) = D^{+}(L_\alpha(r))$;
- $L_\lambda(r) = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} L_\alpha(r)$, if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal.
- $L(r) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathsf{Ord}} L_\alpha(x)$.

The set $\mathsf{trcl}(A)$ is the transitive closure of $A$, and $D^{+}(A)$ is the set of all sets definable in $A$ with or without parameters in $A$.

Comment: Here is a sketch, but this is the wrong forum foe this question: Suppose it is not a limit in $L (r) $. So it is there the successor of, say, $\lambda $. In reality, $\lambda $ is countable, so find a suitable real $s $ that codes a well-ordering of $\omega $ in type $\lambda $, and now let $t $ be a real coding $r $ and $s $. Check that $L (t) $ computes $\omega_1$ correctly. To see that limit cardinals in $L (r) $ are strong limit cardinals, check that in fact $\mathsf{GCH} $ holds in $L (r) $.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you for the reply. I was trying something along the lines, but working with strong limits instead. This made me realize that there is a mistake in the definition of $L_0(r)$: it should be $\mathsf{trcl(\{r\})}$, as otherwise we cannot ensure $r \in L(r)$.

Comment: It doesn't matter much. You could even have $L_0(r)$ be the empty set, as long as there is some stage where $r$ appears. This is ensured if you choose the language of the structure appropriately (besides $\in$, a predicate symbol for $r$, for example). The point here is that $r$ is a set of ordinals. For a general set, yes, you better start with the transitive closure.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh, I see. Thank you very much for your time.